# Eclipse: How to run a project from svn?

Tags: eclipse, svn, project

I recently imported a project via svn in eclipse.
Works fine, BUT I see no option to run it.
When I try to create a run configuration (Java Application), the "Project:" Textfield is empty and the "Browse" dialog as well...
Is there anything special to setup to run a project imported via SVN?
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing special about a project imported from SVN.

Comment: SVN doesn't "run" projects.  It's just a repository for source tracking.  If the code doesn't have a context in which it can run, that has nothing to do with where the code files are saved.

Comment: @greg Thank you. Creating and running a normal application is no problem though.

Comment: @David right, but it is just a normal java application, I ran it already on the computer I created it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the Project and select **Run as** > **Java Application**. Eclipse should search through the project to find a class with a `main()` method. That will create a launch configuration for you, which you could then edit and modify if you need to.

Comment: This is my problem, eclipse does (as it seems) not do that.
I've put up a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/MtazjM9.png

Comment: That looks like the project is not created as a Java project, but rather a "General" project. It must be created as a Java project in order for Eclipse to give it Java capabilities, such as running it.

Comment: That was it. I imported it again from svn, selecting the java project-wizard. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Note that it is usually recommended to check in the `.project` and `.classpath` files into your source code repository; if those files are present, Eclipse will automatically import it as a Java project. It makes importing a single-step, nearly trivial process.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a java application, you have to specify the class to run, and the class should have main method. (public static void main(String[] args) )

reference : http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-jdk-ide-tutorials/253-beginners-eclipse-tutorial-how-run-first-java-application-eclipse.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes the project does have a main-method, it already ran on the other computer. But neither does the project itself appear in the selection list in the run configurations dialog, nor the main, or any class.